# python power operator strange behaviour

Tags: python, exponentiation

I am trying to implement multivariate gaussian pdf. I have a strange issue with the `**` operator.The code is

```
def multi_var(x,mu,cov):
   #Multivariate gaussian
   print (1/2*np.pi)**(len(x)/2)
   return(((1/2*np.pi)**(len(x)/2))/np.sqrt(np.abs(np.linalg.det(cov)))*np.exp(np.dot(np.matrix.transpose(x-mu),np.dot(np.linalg.inv(cov),(x-mu)))))
```

In the command it gives

```
>>> print multi_var(np.matrix('0;0;4'),np.matrix('0;0;6'),np.matrix([[.3,.67,8],[2,3,8],    [2,.05,2]]))
2
[[ 0.]]
```

When I execute the same code from command line

```
>>> x=np.matrix('0;0;4')
>>> print (1/2*np.pi)**(len(x)/2)
```

I get

```
 1.96870124322
```

Comment: In Python 2, `1/2` and `len(x) / 2` uses *integer division*, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes,this is python 2.7, spyder IDE from Anaconda stack

Comment: `1/2` is `0` unless you use float division.

Comment: No, But in command line it works well,why in script?? that solved the problem anyway thanks...

Comment: Most likely because your command line is Python 3, not Python 2.